# Positioning social media icons in middle of footer div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, positioning

I can't figure out how to position the social media icons in the middle of the footer under the contact me button and make the whole footer stick to the bottom without the lorem ipsum text. Please help

https://codepen.io/Sankyeat/pen/VybeLY

Heres the footer code:

```
<div class="container">
          <footer class="bg-dark">
            <div class="row">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-info mx-auto">Contact Me</a>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-3 social">
              <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
          </footer>
        </div>

.footer {
  height: 100px;
}

.social {

  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;

}
```

Comment: The codepen does not show the social media icons but they do appear on the browser during development

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-center` class.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <footer class="bg-dark">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-md-4 text-center'>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info mx-auto">Contact Me</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-md-4 text-center">
      <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```